# how to restrict the max size of a keyspace cassandra?

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-2.0

Could you please tell me if we can restrict the size of a keyspace. We want to make an application restrict the size they can grow inside the cassandra.

Thanks,
Kamal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do that, you'll have against the basic logic of cassandra that consist on a scalable database (unlimited size in theory). There is no way to limit the size of your keyspace.